# "Mapping conflict!" Error in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have Installed an ELK stack on my machine. Kibana's version in 5.2.1, Elastic version is 5.2.1. So basically everything is uptodate.
But now i am getting following warning.

**"Mapping conflict! 2 fields are defined as several types (string, integer, etc) across the indices that match this pattern. You may still be able to use these conflict fields in parts of Kibana, but they will be unavailable for functions that require Kibana to know their type. Correcting this issue will require reindexing your data."**

and those two fields are "**geoip.coordinates**" and "**geoip.location**"

i search for the solutions on google and got result like "ReIndex data". but i am new to ELK and dont know how to reindex it

Here's my **template.json** file,

```
{
"mappings": {
"_default_": {
  "_all": {
    "enabled": true,
    "norms": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "template1": {
        "mapping": {
          "doc_values": true,
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "{dynamic_type}"
        },
        "match": "*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "offset": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "geoip"  : {
      "type" : "object",
      "dynamic": true,
      "properties" : {
        "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
        "coordinates" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
 "settings": {
  "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
},
"template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

and my logstash.conf file's output section,

```
output {

 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

I don't know what should be the solution. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is very much likely that you have several `filebeat-*` indexes and in one of them, the `geoip.location` and `geoip.coordinates` fields were not declared as `geo_point` but as a string instead. Maybe you didn't have the template installed at that time. Possible?

Comment: so how can i fix that ?

Comment: How many indexes do you have?

Comment: one index named filebeat:-*

i went to kibana-->management-->index patterns to get this answer is this right ?

Answer (score 1):

write `GET /_cat/indices?v` command in the elasticsearch console to get the information about all the indexes. "kibana-->management-->index patterns" does not tell you about all the indexes that you have. It simply tells you the index patterns that you have configured.

Comment: did that and i got multiple results like this,

**yellow open   filebeat-2017.04.29             IPa9v_5GQB6-EOXovKVCWg   5   1     465671            0    388.3mb        388.3mb**


i followed this [https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime] site to reindex without downtime but no luck

Comment: are you sure that the reindex operation went well, without any errors ? @Easy-Install

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the new field to kibana you most decide, which type is it.
After it - you would try to edit your /etc/logstash/conf.d/filters.conf:

```
filter {
  if [headers][request_path] == "/stats/" {
    ...
    mutate {
      remove_field => "[headers]"
      convert => {
        "intCourseId"                   => "integer"
        "intLessonId"                   => "integer"
        "intQuestionId"                 => "integer"
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you follow this pattern, you will not have a conflict.

Else, you can fix incorrect field values in elasticsearch indexes. Kibana will reindexing its tomorrow.
My script on ruby do it:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# find and replace incorrect field values in elasticsearch indexes.
# Run:
# ruby ./bin/fix_elk_attribute_conflict elk_user=<name> elk_password=<password> index_type=<index_type> host=<host_ip>
#      port=<host_port> attribute_name=<attribute_name> attribute_check_regexp='^\d+$'
#   name, password                  - nginx basic auth credentials
#   index_type=<index_type>         - type of elasticsearch indexes
#   host=<host_ip> port=<host_port> - host&port of elasticsearch node
#   attribute_name=<attribute_name> - name of field which need to correct
#   attribute_check_regexp          - regexp for check if value is String
#

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

command_line_arguments = Hash[ARGV.map { |x| x.split('=') }]
USER_NAME = command_line_arguments['elk_user']
USER_PASSWORD = command_line_arguments['elk_password']
INDEX_NAME = command_line_arguments['index_type']
HOST = command_line_arguments['host']
PORT = command_line_arguments['port']
ATTRIBUTE_NAME = command_line_arguments['attribute_name']
ATTRIBUTE_CHECK_REGEXP = Regexp.new(command_line_arguments['attribute_check_regexp'])

def update_document(index_id:, doc_id:, request_body:)
  url = "http://#{USER_NAME}@#{HOST}:#{PORT}/#{index_id}/#{INDEX_NAME}/#{doc_id}"
  puts url: url
  puts request_body: request_body
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri)
  request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  request.basic_auth USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD
  request.body = JSON.dump(request_body) if request_body

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  puts request_complete_with_massage: data
end

def find_all_documents(command:, request_body: nil)
  uri = URI.parse("http://#{USER_NAME}@#{HOST}:#{PORT}#{command}")
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  request.basic_auth USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD
  request.body = JSON.dump(request_body) if request_body

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  {
    result: (data['hits'] || {})['hits'] || [],
    total: (data['hits'] || {})['total']
  }
end

doc_pointer = 0
page_size = 100
total_count = page_size + 100
total_count_message = true
errors = []

while doc_pointer < total_count do
  documents = find_all_documents(command: '/_search?pretty', request_body: {
    from: doc_pointer,
    size: page_size,
    _source: [:_id, "#{ATTRIBUTE_NAME}"],
    query: {
      exists: {
        field: "#{ATTRIBUTE_NAME}"
      }
    }
  })
  if total_count_message
    puts "Found #{documents[:total]} documents with attribute \"#{ATTRIBUTE_NAME}\"."
    puts
    total_count = documents[:total]
    total_count_message = false
  end
  printf "\r Reading documents #{doc_pointer} - #{doc_pointer + page_size}"

  documents[:result].each do |doc|
    attribute_value = doc['_source'][ATTRIBUTE_NAME]
    if !attribute_value
      errors << {
        attribute_value: attribute_value,
        doc: doc['_id'],
        index: doc['_index'],
        message: "Document #{doc['_id']} have empty #{ATTRIBUTE_NAME} == '#{attribute_value}'",
        correct_attribute_value: '0',
      }
    elsif !attribute_value.is_a? String
      errors << {
        attribute_value: attribute_value,
        doc: doc['_id'],
        index: doc['_index'],
        message: "Document #{doc['_id']} have not string #{ATTRIBUTE_NAME} == '#{attribute_value}'",
        correct_attribute_value: attribute_value.to_s,
      }
    elsif !attribute_value[ATTRIBUTE_CHECK_REGEXP]
      errors << {
        attribute_value: attribute_value,
        doc: doc['_id'],
        index: doc['_index'],
        message: "Document #{doc['_id']} contains incorrect #{ATTRIBUTE_NAME} == '#{attribute_value}'",
        correct_attribute_value: '0',
      }
    end
  end
  doc_pointer += page_size
end
puts

if errors.size > 0
  puts "============ Errors found ============="
  errors.each do |error, index|
    puts index
    puts error[:message]
    puts doc: error[:doc]
    puts index: error[:index]
    puts ATTRIBUTE_NAME: ATTRIBUTE_NAME
    puts attribute_value: error[:attribute_value]

    fix_hash = {}
    fix_hash[ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = error[:correct_attribute_value]
    update_document(index_id: error[:index], doc_id: error[:doc], request_body: fix_hash)

    puts 'Value corrected to': error[:correct_attribute_value]
    puts
  end
else
  puts 'All values of attribute is ok.'
end
```